# Maximizing Acrobat Window Leaves a Big Margin

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I don't know where the problem is, but it seems as if now each time when I try to maximize the Acrobat window there is a big margin on the right and at the bottom.

[image: Screenshot]

Has anyone also encountered this problem before? Is there any quick solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Which version of Windows are you running this thing on?

Comment: @pipitas: Windows 7 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you click on the '100%' dropdown in the menu and select a different scaling factor (f.e. 'scale to window width' or whatever it's labelled in English)?